# rediercting to parent page in php included in subfolder using JS

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP file that placed in sub-folder and have an "href" of a parent HTML page echoed as an alert message to redirect to that page after hitting OK.

simply it looks like this:

```
parent_page.PHP

 /PHP

   file.php
```

I used all the supposed formats such as ./ or ../ and even a single slash but none of them are working and it redirects me to a page that says : object not found.

here is the actual code

```
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.location.href='page_parent.php';
 alert('$message');</script>";
```

thanks.

Comment: Try making the URL relative from the document root by adding `/` in front of it. Something like: `href="/page_parent.php"` or `href="/folder-name/parent_page.php"`.

Comment: I did as you suggested but it still redirects me to( http://localhost/project_name/php/parent_page.php) rather than (http://localhost/project_name/parent_page.php) .. any reason why?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I have no idea why...

Comment: I don't know what to show exactly, but the idea is redirecting to the previous page if that will help.